# DataHandler to be passed a Base64 image string in Java apache.cxf

Tags: java, spring-boot, image, cxf

I have a byte[] image that I converted to Base64 string. I then need to send this image over to a SOAP service as request payload below which is the signature.

How do I send this in the DataHandler? Most of what I see are javax.activation examples and I'm tied to jakarta version as my WSDL is generating this.

DataHandler belongs to `import jakarta.activation.DataHandler`

Could you advise how to handle this?

```
public void setDfile(DataHandler value) {
    this.dfile = value;
}
```